# solving second order linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Can somebody please show me how to solve the following differential equation:

$$
a\ddot{x} + b\dot{x} = c
$$
given these initial conditions $x(0) = 2$, $\dot{x}(0) = 0.5$ and $a = 4, b = 1.5$

First I tried to find the homogeneous solution:

$$
a\ddot{x} + b\dot{x} = 0
$$

$$
a\ddot{x} = -b\dot{x}
$$
then take the integral on both sides:

$$
a\frac{dx}{dt} = -bx - C1
$$

$$
\frac{a}{bx+C1}dx = dt
$$
integrate again
$$
\int\frac{a}{bx+C1}dx = \int dt
$$
which should equal to this:
$$
\frac{a}{b}log(C1+bx) + C2 = t
$$
which results to something like this
$$
(C1 + bx)^{\frac{a}{b}} = 10^{t-C2}
$$
But I don't know how to proceed in order to solve for x.

Using the Laplacetransform I got this far:

$$
a(s^2X(s)-sx(0)-\dot{x}(0)) + b(sX(s)-x(0)) = C(s) = 0
$$

$$
as^2X(s)-asx(0)-a\dot{x}(0) + bsX(s)-bx(0) = C(s) = 0
$$

$$
4s^2X(s)-s8-2 + 1.5sX(s)-3 = C(s) = 0
$$

$$
X(s)(s^2a+sb) = s8+5
$$

$$
X(s) = \frac{s8+5}{s^2a+sb} = \frac{s8}{s^2a+sb}+ \frac{5}{s^2a+sb}
$$
But I couldn't find a suitable backtransformation in my formulary.
And I am already struggling with the homogenous solution...
Can you please give me a hint on how to proceed and which approach to choose?
I need to find the time response of x(t).

Comment: Just name $x'$ a different letter and you can get a first order ODE.

Comment: Nice hint, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making this harder than it needs to be, since working with the velocity gives a tracable equation right away.

Let $v = \frac{dx}{dt}$, then
$$\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{c - bv}{a} \\
dt = \frac{a}{c - bv} dv\\
t+k = -\frac{a}{b} \ln (c - bv)\\
v=\frac{c-\kappa e^{-\frac{tb}{a}}}{b}
$$
Now with $v(0) = \frac12$ we have 
$$
c-\kappa = \frac{b}{2} \\
\kappa = c-\frac{b}{2}
$$

Final step is solving 
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{c-\kappa e^{-\frac{tb}{a}}}{b}
$$
$$
x = \frac{\kappa}{a} e^{-\frac{tb}{a}}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much, this is helpful! I couldn't see that